# How to change the text and its color using the value of a variable (i)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hi i'm trying to change the text and its color depending upon the value of the variable "i" and not using any eventlisteners! i'm getting cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null error is there any fix to this! thank you!

```js
var i = 0;      
var images= [];
var time = 3000;  
var eventaction=0;
var timeoutId;

var dynamictext=document.querySelector("dynamictext");



images[0] = "https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f4/92/39/f492399e154bd9f564d7fc5299c19911--purple-rain-deep-purple.jpg";
images[1] = "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/purple-butterfly-isolated-on-white-260nw-44004850.jpg";
images[2] = "https://www.birdscanada.org/images/inbu_norm_q_townsend.jpg";


function changeImg()
{if(i<images.length-1)
{i++;
}else
{i=0;}
document.getElementById('sliders').src=images[i];eventaction=0;
dynamictextchanger();
} 
timeoutId=setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}



function dynamictextchanger()
{
   if(i==1)
    {
      dynamictext.innerHTML="Starter";
      dynamicetxt.style.color="black";
    }
    else if(i==2)
    {
      dynamictext.innerHTML="veg";
      dynamicetxt.style.color="green";
    }
    else if(i==3)
    {
      dynamictext.innerHTML="nonveg";
      dynamicetxt.style.color="red";
    }
  }






window.onload=changeImg;
```

```html
<p id="dynamictext"/>

<button class="button button3" id="leftbutton"> previous</button>
<img id="sliders" />

<button class="button button3" id="rightbutton">next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code has way too many errors. I don't even know where to start. But some of these fixes should get you up and running.

- Incorrect variable `dynamicetxt`.
- Missing hash # symbol in `querySelector` method
- Extra `}`

```js
var i = 0;      
var images= [];
var time = 3000;  
var eventaction=0;
var timeoutId;

var dynamictext = document.querySelector("#dynamictext");

images[0] = "https://i.pinimg.com/236x/f4/92/39/f492399e154bd9f564d7fc5299c19911--purple-rain-deep-purple.jpg";
images[1] = "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/purple-butterfly-isolated-on-white-260nw-44004850.jpg";
images[2] = "https://www.birdscanada.org/images/inbu_norm_q_townsend.jpg";

function changeImg()
{

if(i < images.length - 1) i++;
else i = 0;

document.getElementById('sliders').src=images[i];

eventaction=0;
dynamictextchanger(i);

timeoutId = setTimeout(changeImg, time);
}



function dynamictextchanger(i)
{
   if(i==0)
    {
      dynamictext.innerHTML="Starter";
      dynamictext.style.color="black";
    }
    else if(i==1)
    {
      dynamictext.innerHTML="veg";
      dynamictext.style.color="green";
    }
    else if(i==2)
    {
      dynamictext.innerHTML="nonveg";
      dynamictext.style.color="red";
    }
  }

window.onload = function(){ changeImg(); }
```

```html
<p id="dynamictext"></p>

<button class="button button3" id="leftbutton"> previous</button>
<img id="sliders" />

<button class="button button3" id="rightbutton">next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the `#` sign on this line:

```
var dynamictext=document.querySelector("#dynamictext");
```